# How to "use" MESSAGE-DIGEST() in PROGRESS OPENEDGE?

Tags: security, sha256, openedge, progress-4gl

I'm working with an Openedge Webserver (PASOE). Currently, attempting to use the MESSAGE-DIGEST() to apply "SHA-256" encryption.

```
MESSAGE-DIGEST("SHA-256", "sampleString").
```

This creates a RAW value that I can only view after applying string().

This value doesn't correspond to what's created with SHA-256 encryption:
[image]...I'm assuming this is due to the string()? Also, without having access to the MESSAGE-DIGEST() how can one generate the same encryption with say JavaScript for example? Sorry if I'm completely misunderstanding the usage of this function, but any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MESSAGE-DIGEST` will return a raw 32-byte value. You simply need to use `HEX-ENCODE` to convert it:

```
DEFINE VARIABLE cString AS CHARACTER   NO-UNDO.

cString = "sampleText".

MESSAGE STRING(HEX-ENCODE(MESSAGE-DIGEST("sha-256", cString))) VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX.
```

Comment: Thanks again Jensd. It would be a huge help if Progress linked these things in their [documentation](https://documentation.progress.com/output/ua/OpenEdge_latest/index.html#page/dvref/message-digest-function.html) 

[I.e. See Also](https://documentation.progress.com/output/ua/OpenEdge_latest/index.html#page/dvref/hex-encode-function.html)

Doesn't that make sense?

Comment: The Knowledge base does mention that, but only for SHA1-DIGEST and MD5-DIGEST:
https://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/P115990/p
https://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/000043512/p
https://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/000060269/p

Comment: @idspispopd Same principle applies. It's better to use the MESSAGE-DIGEST function. (MD5 and SHA1 should probably be avoided). Progress however rarely removes older functions.

Comment: @N8BIZ The knowledgebase (https://knowledgebase.progress.com/) contains LOTS if good information like this if you happen to find it. Unfortunately it's not a part of the "online help" in AppBuilder/OpenEdge Studio. I prefer to search it via google: "site:knowledgebase.progress.com <phrase>"